# Newton's optimization: why wouldn't the results be good if we take $x_0$ between $(-\frac{1}{\sqrt 3},\frac{1}{\sqrt 3})$ for $f(x)= x^3- x-1\;?$

Tags: calculus, optimization

I was reading about the numerical method of Newton for finding the roots of $f(x)$ in *Thomas' Calculus* ; the author presented an example

> Find the x-coordinate of the point where the curve $f(x)= x^3 -x$ crosses the horizontal line
>   Solution The curve crosses the line $y=1\;.$

After finding the solution, he wrote:

> The curve has a local maximum at $x= \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$ and a local minimum
>   at $\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}\;.$ We would not expect good results from Newton’s method if we were to start with $x_0$ between these points, but we can start any place to the right of $x= \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$ and get the answer.

Now, why did he tell so?

so, while guessing the first estimate $x_0\;,$ won't I take a number between a local maximum & local minimum?

I'm not getting this point? Is it a general statement or only specific to this problem?

Comment: The sentence in first highlighted section is broken. I suggest the part between the two occurrences of "line" (inclusive) be collapsed to just one "line"; it makes more sense that way.

Comment: Draw a graph and think about how the next term in the sequence is generated geometrically.

Comment: Maybe you can edit either text or caption?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://www.google.de/search?q=f(x)%3Dx3%E2%88%92x%E2%88%921&rlz=1C1GTPM_deDE531DE531&oq=f(x)%3Dx3%E2%88%92x%E2%88%921&aqs=chrome..69i57.478j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=plot+y%3Dx%5E3%E2%88%92x%E2%88%921) plot. 
 As you can easily see for values greater than $\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$ you the newton algorithm converges towards the zero. 
 However if you start between $\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$ and $-\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$ the tangent has a negativ increase and therefore $x_1 \le -\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$ so you moved away from the zero. For those $x_1$ $\frac {df(x)}{dx}$ is going to have a rather big value. 
 $x_2$ is going to be smaller then $\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$, maybe even smaller then $\frac{-1}{\sqrt3}$. Now $x_3$ (because its either similiar to $x_1$ or smaller then $\frac{-1}{\sqrt3}$) is again smaller then $\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$ and obviously the algorithm does not converge fast. If you get a point closely to the left of the local maximum then it an be seen that in converges, however thats going to take a lot more steps then if you started right of the local minimum.

Example:

- red    : $x_0 = 0$    $y_0 = -1$      $\frac {df(x)}{dx}(x_0) = -1$
- green  : $x_1 = -1$   $y_1 = -1$      $\frac {df(x)}{dx}(x_1) = 2$
- yellow : $x_2 = -0.5$ $y_2 = -0.6125$ $\frac {df(x)}{dx}(x_2) \approx 0.1$
  ...

[image]

Comment: You should use `\le` instead of `<=`; the result would yield $\le\;.$

Comment: @user36790 thanks, especially for turning \ge into \le

Comment: When you ask your scientific calculator to solve the equation, you would get the same result as Newton's method yields i.e., $1.324717957\;.$ But if you separately cube it and then subtract it minus 1, you wouldn't get $0\;!$ I can't figure out why this is so.

Comment: You mean the zero? Its an iterative approach?

Comment: Yes, 0. First the calculator gives the root but if you separately use the root (cube it, minus it, -1), then $0$ doesn't come.

Comment: 1.324717957^3 = 2.32471795596, 2.32471795596-1-1.324717957 should roughly be 0.

Comment: I thought it should give exact zero; for it is the root of the equation, isn't it?

Comment: This is a numerical approach, not an analytical one. It reduces the error in each iteration step and whilest it converges against the solution it never reaches it. Also how do you want to represent an irrational number in decimal?

Comment: Thanks, for sticking to all of my queries; +1.

Comment: The reason the zero is not 1 as in your quote is that your title says $y=x^3-x-1$, whereas your quote says $y=x^3-x$.